# ASP.Net UserControls not firings Any AutoPost Back or Click Events

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, autopostback, web-user-controls, webusercontrols

I have ASP.Net Project which developed in VS 2017 Enterprise Edition.

What happened I upgraded the SQL Server Data Tools and VS Updates. After that my ObjectDataSource DataAdapter Wizard for my StoredProcedures start giving an error with SQL. (it was might due to DataTools Upgrade)

I tried many things to resolve the issue by searching on the Internet but no luck then finally I removed the VS 2017 and DataTools from PC.

After that, I Installed again the VS 2017 Enterprise Edition. Now this time the DataAdapter Wizard Error was gone, but when I run the Project seems everything is working fine which is on ASP.net Pages itself like LinkButtons, Href, and other post back events, but those ASP.net Pages which has User Controls those user controls are not firing anything, No AutoPostBack or Click event, no LinkButton Click event. The only thing is working on those controls is href.

I have around 75 Pages and that much of User Controls and none of those controls are firing anything. Those were just fine yesterday before to upgrade the VS.

There is another thing after New Installation of VS when I was running the Project: it was showing JavaScript Debugging Page Before loading the actual page, so I disabled the JavaScript Debugging from Tools >> Options. But that has nothing to do with that bug I guess coz I tested it by enabling and disabling the same thing. None of the controls is firing anything.

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools console for any javascript errors?  When you are referring to user controls not firing anything you mean the events of standard controls e.g. buttons inside user controls or user control custom events?

Comment: Just realized not only this project but my all other projects having the same issue......so that means there is bug in VS..